# Each convergent filter has at most one cluster point

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. It is not too hard to show that $X$ is a Hausdorff space if and only if each filter has at most one limit.

Suppose now that each convergent filter has at most one cluster point. Can we say anything about how this property relates to the Hausdorff criterion?

**Idea:** The limit of a convergent filter is a cluster point. So each convergent filter has a unique limit. Thus each filter has at most one limit. Therefore, $X$ is Hausdorff.

Have I missed something obvious here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, is correct, because every limit point of a filter is a cluster point:
Let $x\in X$ be a limit point of a filter $\mathcal{F}$. Then for every $U \subseteq X$ open such that $x\in U$, $U\in \mathcal{F}$. So $U\cap F \neq \emptyset$,  for every $F\in \mathcal{F}$, and therefore $x\in cl(F)$, for every $F\in \mathcal{F}$.

Then if every filter $\mathcal{F}$ has at most one cluster point, then has at most one limit point, so $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Great. I suppose another way of seeing it is to rephrase the first result: $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if no filter converges to more than one distinct limit.