# Is the finite intersection of elements in filters always non-empty?

Tags: general-topology, limits, filters

I know that $\forall A,B\in \mathcal F$, we have $A\cap B\in \mathcal F$.

However, in the [proof that every limit point of $\mathcal F$ is a cluster point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3196364/each-convergent-filter-has-at-most-one-cluster-point), they use $\forall A,B\in\mathcal F$ implies $ A\cap B\neq \phi$. Is this always true?

Comment: There is only one filter containing the empty set: the filter of all subsets.

Comment: @markvs, but why did they use $U\cap F\neq \phi,\forall U,F\in \mathcal F$ in the proof?

Comment: @markvs, I meant the auther of the proof in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3196364/each-convergent-filter-has-at-most-one-cluster-point

Answer (score 0):

There are two axioms for filters that are relevant:

- For all $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$: $A \cap B \in \mathcal{F}$ (i.e. filters are closed under finite intersections).
- $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{F}$.

From these two your claim immediately follows: the intersection of $A$ and $B$ is in the filter so the intersection cannot be empty.

This indeed implies that for every filter that converges to $x$ in some Hausdorff space $X$, that $x$ is the unique cluster point of that filter: If $y \neq x$ find disjoint neighbourhoods $U_x$ and $U_y$ of $x$ resp. $y$. By convergence, $U_x \in \mathcal{F}$ so by the above we have that $U_y$ is a neighbourhood of $y$ that is disjoint from a filter member (namely $U_x$) which exactly means (by the definition of a cluster point: every neighbourhood intersects every filter member) that $y$ is not a cluster point of $\mathcal{F}$.